# jQuery change text of a button into text of clicked button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When an anchor of a  submenu inside an anchor button of a menu is selected... i want the text of the button to be changed into that of the anchor of the submenu. Also if the text is more than 12 characters.. it should be changed into the first 9 characters followed by '...'

The HTML of this menu is:

```
                <ul class="role-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Podcast</a></li>
                    <li class="viewby-role">
                        <a href="#">View by Role</a>
                        <ul class="viewby-inner">
                            <li><a href="#">View all Roles</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Blount</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lieutenant</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Suppose when 'lieutenant' is clicked 'View by Role' text should change into 'lietenant'.

Is this possible using jQuery? Very stuck in this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.viewby-inner a').on('click', function() {
    var text = $(this).text();

    text = text.length >= 12 ? text.slice(0, 9) + '...' : text;

    $('.viewby-role a:first').text(text);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7r3tV/)

Comment: oh wow.. this works perfectly... thanks..  will accept as answer after the initial waiting period.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have several blocks of `role-menu` or several sub-menus within it, the following should do it for all:

```
$('.viewby-inner a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var targ = $(this).closest('li.viewby-role').children('a').first(),
        txt = this.text;
    txt = txt.length > 12 ? txt.substring(0,9) + '...' : txt;
    targ.text( txt );
});
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/2T82Z/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$('.viewby-inner a').on('click', function() {
      var text = $(this).text();
     text = text.length >= 12 ? text.substr(0, 9) + '...' : text;

    $('.viewby-role a:first').text(text);
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LL8gw/1/)